# dynamic var in a loop using a passed array using node and pug

Tags: pug

I'm not even sure if I can word it right. I'm trying to create a loop that iterates through a passed in array of images. If I call the image directly it works as expected

console.log(p.image1)

but I can't figure out how to do it for a loop. I know there is a way I just can't find it.

I have tried several different ways to get it done but I keep coding in circles.

This is my model:
...

```
prodImages:[
    {
        image1: {type: String,required: false},
        image2: {type: String,required: false},
        image3: {type: String,required: false},
        ...
    }
]
```

This is my controller:
...

```
 const product = await Product.findById(prodId);
 const prodImages = product.prodImages;
    try{
      res.render('admin/edit-product', {
        prodImages: prodImages,
        ...
      }
    }
```

This is my loop written in Pug:
...

```
-var i = 1
each p in prodImages
    while i < 21
    //- p.image1 returns image1 name from db
    mixin image(p, i, title)
        -var prodImg = 'p.'
        -var img = 'image' + i
        -var imageLink = prodImg + img
        img.product-img(src='/images/' + imageLink, id='image' + i, alt=title)
        +image(p, i, product.title)
            - i++
```

I would like the output to be:

```
img class="product-img" src="/images/87b0e842d4f503f96b86d0106de08fd2.jpg " id="image1" alt="title"
```

but I'm getting:

```
img class="product-img" src="/images/p.image1" id="image1" alt="title"
```

This is my console output:

```
CoreMongooseArray [
    { _id: 5c2093e4328e48573485d0aa,
    image1: '87b0e842d4f503f96b86d0106de08fd2.jpg',
    image2: '35f6b5501e409f55efabe428909aebb1.jpg',
    image3: 'd5a90b18a1e40905c6ca49318ccbd33e.jpg',
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved!! This is the solution I finally figured out.

```
-var i = 1
each img in prodImages
    while i < 21
        - var imageName = 'image' + i
        - var image = img[imageName]
        mixin image(image, i, title)
           img.product-img(src='/images/' + image, id='image' + i, alt=title)
        +image(image, i, product.title)
        - i++
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in how the data is passed.  This seems to be a one-element array, where the single element has keys for each image:

```
prodImages:[
    {
        image1: {type: String,required: false},
        image2: {type: String,required: false},
        image3: {type: String,required: false},
        ...
    }
]
```

You can fix this in one of two ways.  The easiest will be to just access the single element in the loop:

```
each image in prodImages[0]
  p= prodImages[0][image]['type'] + " : " +  prodImages[0][image]['required']
```

A little confusing, no?

A better option would be to transform the input data into an array like this:

```
prodImages:[
  {type: String,required: false},
  {type: String,required: false},
  {type: String,required: false},
  ...
]
```

A JavaScript array is guaranteed to iterate in the correct order, but an object with keys does not have guaranteed iteration order.  For this alone you're better with the transformed input.

Anyway, if you transform your prodImages array like the above example then your pug loop will be nice and simple:

```
each image in prodImages
  p= image.type + " : " + image.required
```